# Tailwinds css - How can I vertically align table cell content to the top of a row?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am trying to figure out how to align the data of a table cell to the top of the table row.

```html
  <tr className="flex-1 items-center align-top">

    <td className=" py-1 pl-1 pr-1 text-sm sm:pl-6">
       <div className="flex-1 items-center align-top">
           <div className="flex-1 items-center align-top">
                <p className="flex-1 items-center align-top">
                    title 
                </p>
                <p className="flex-1 align-top">
                    short multi line sentence about one third the length of the sentence in the next column, I want both cells to align to the top.
                </p>
           </div>
        </div>
    </td>
```

I have seen this [article](https://koenwoortman.com/tailwind-css-vertical-align-flexbox/) which says that if I want to align data vertically, I have to use `items-center` in the flex class. I tried this but the content still renders in the vertical center.

The next column has about twice the data, so the cell data in this column is displayed in the vertical center. I want it to align to the top of the row.

How can I do that?

Comment: Any chance the intended class on container could be `flex` to make it a flex container, instead of `flex-1`?

Comment: I tried both flex and flex-1 - which is shown in the docs

Answer (score 0):

As John Li points out, you probably meant to use `flex`, as `flex-1` is not useful without being inside of a wrapper which has `flex`.

You don't actually need all of the wrapper divs and your cell content should align to the top without using `items-` or `align-`.

```html
<table>
  <tr class="flex gap-4 p-1 text-sm sm:pl-6">
    <td>
      <p>title</p>
      <p>short multi line sentence about one third the length of the sentence in the next column, I want both cells to align to the top.</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Longer multiline sentence...</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Sandbox here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/QPUuacC4Rj